# JTAG on a board with optional components

Tags: jtag

This feels like it ought to be a common problem with a conventional solution, but I'm struggling to find one.

I am designing a board with several JTAG-conforming components. It has a mezzanine with another.

The mezzanine may or may not be fitted.

How can I arrange that JTAG works properly both with the board present and absent?

The obvious, but clunky, solution would be to fit a TDI-TDO link when the board was absent. Perhaps a TDI-TDO tristate buffer with pull-down on nOE, driven high by a presence-sense line from the board?

Obviously, with JTAG I care a great deal about robustness. Is that robust? Are there any complications to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just connect TDI and TDO of the mezzanine with a 10k resistor, under the assumption that TDO drive strength is good enough against that.

Comment: Tempting. But it would be really nice to be adopting a tried and tested strategy. Do you know of that working reliably for anyone in the field?

Comment: @Clive, it depends on your components. If they have a proper output driver on TDO, it works, otherwise, it doesn't. You can try this with the normal JTAG setup by checking whether communication still works when you pull TDO high or low.